# prevent gimbal lock on angle-axis transformation with rotation of 90 degree in y-axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, 3d

I would like to put a sticker on the surface of target. I use a depth cam and a robotics arm.

The setting is like this. 
[image]

I know there will be gimbal lock on y axis because the target is parallel to z axis.

```
M1: cam2targetT:
 0.933286 -0.358041 0.0279849 -0.250368
-0.162293 -0.489985  -0.85649 0.0660773
 0.320371  0.794808 -0.515404   1.03789
        0         0         0         1

M2: arm2camT:
        0  0.707107  0.707107       0.1
        1         0         0      0.53
        0  0.707107 -0.707107      0.96
        0         0         0         1

Mf: arm2tagetT:
 0.111778  0.215542 -0.970075  0.880623
 0.933286 -0.358041 0.0279849  0.279632
-0.341295 -0.908486 -0.241184  0.272825
        0         0         0         1
```

When i send the command to UR hand, it is in this format.
I used this

```
Eigen::AngleAxisd newAngleAxis(mat);
std::cout << newAngleAxis.angle() << "\n" << newAngleAxis.axis() << "\n\n";
```

and i got this:
3.87376
 0.700441
 0.470301
-0.536842

The final command to UR is this pose.

```
Mf in axis-angle T:
0.880623,0.279632,0.272825
AngleAxisd R:
2.71334,1.82184,-2.0796
```

And as expected, gimbal lock happened, so what question is, how can I find the correct angle-axis in this case? is the problem can be solved by quaternions and how?

P.S. I don't think I can change the rotation order in UR.

Comment: Hi, so the I don't think the problem here is really gimbal lock, as you are only performing 2 rotations, I think your matrices are just calculated incorrectly or multiplied in the wrong order or something. Without more information about what you're trying to do with the rotations and what kind of result you expect, I can't really help you.

Comment: thanks for reply. i would like to put a sticker on the surface of target. I use a depth cam and a robotics arm.

Comment: Ok, so what information do you have, and what information are you solving for? Is it like you know the position and rotation of the arm and the rotation of the camera and you're trying to get the position that the sticker needs to be at?

Comment: Also, could you please provide an example set of inputs?

Comment: you are right, the problem is I made mistake in finding plane normal of vertical plane, this method "setModelType(pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE); " gave a normal of plane, but I am not sure when it is to point to the left or to right.